# typescript tsconfig, app.ts and app.js files in a different folder

Tags: typescript

I have the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./public",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  }
}
```

and I'd like to make the following output when I'm compiling the app.ts file into app.js:

```
MyProject
├── tsconfig.json
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── app.js
├── src
│   ├── app.ts
```

How I can achieve the app.js file output be in the public folder?

What did I do wrong in the config file? I keep reading the official documents but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Your tsconfig.json seems correct. How do you compile the app? With `tsc` command?

Comment: yes, I typed `tsc app.ts` in the src folder and it just creates the app.js file there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tsconfig.json` is correct. However, it depends on how `tsc` command is run.

If you specify an input file, `tsconfig.json` will be ignored and the file will be compiled with the default compiler options:

```
tsc src/app.ts
```

**Fix**

Run `tsc` without specifying any input files. This will compile files according to your `tsconfig.json`.

```
tsc
```

See documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. When I use the `tsc src/app.ts --outDir public/` command, it works correctly. But this obviously ignores the `tsconfig.json` file. This give me the thought the issue is in the `tsconfig` file somehwhere

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify. But what you need to do is to run `tsc` alone, without any input files.

Comment: ohh I understand, it works now. Thanks so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) with the [typescript loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/). For serving html files, use [html-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)